# How to execute a function in Javascript with a delay and a flag condition (event handler-like)?

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a program in Javascript that takes input strings and then runs a simulation on each string. The user decides how fast, i.e. what the delay should be between processing each string. I'm using the setInterval() function to control this. However, I am running into the issue that longer strings may not be ready to process because the last string is still processing. This causes a slew of errors on my part. Here's some code to paint a better picture.

```
let testingInterval = setInterval(function () {
      strprn.innerHTML = `<h2>${strings[i]}<\h2>`; // displays current string to user
      if (i + 1 == strings.length) { // checks if should notify user all strings have been processed
        checker.finalCheck = true;//the checker uses this flag to notify the user once the test completes
      }
      checker.check(strings[i]); //runs the check i.e. simulation
      i++; // increments the counter iterating through the array (setup code not shown here)
      if (i >= strings.length) { 
        clearInterval(testingInterval); //once we reach the end stop the interval iterating
        evenOutResults(); // clean up answers function
        updateTimeStamp(Date.now()); // for readability, I add a timestamp of when the results were generated
      }
    }, delay); // user specified delay
```

What I'm looking for is a way to honor the delay but also not begin the next call until the current string has finished processing.

Something like this logically (the code below freezes your browser XD):

```
 function delayLoop() {
      setTimeout(function () {
        strprn.innerHTML = `<h2>${strings[i]}<\h2>`;
        if (i + 1 == strings.length){
          checker.finalCheck = true;
        }
        checker.check(strings[i]);
        i++;
        if (i < strings.length) {
          // check if the current string has finished, if so call, else wait until the string is done
          while (checker.processingFlag){
            // console.log('Waiting for current string to finish');
          }
          delayLoop(); // call again
        } else {
          evenOutResults();
          updateTimeStamp(Date.now());
        }
      }, delay);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I should have clarified this more. Checker.check() is a function that uses a setInterval() to display an animation. The animation needs to be done for a set of objects. Because of the setInterval(), anytime we wait means javascript will try to execute the next lines of code. This means vanilla for-loops are out of the question.

My initial solution was to throw the for-loop iteration itself into a setTimeout(). This works as long as the delay is long enough for all the objects being iterated. Problem is the objects rarely are, so if an object was larger than the one it preceded and the delay was short then the whole animation crashed. In the end, Promises were the easiest solution.

```
     let runLoop = async () => {
        for(var i = 0; i < strings.length; i++){
          strprn.innerHTML = `<h2>${strings[i]}<\h2>`;
          console.log("about to await");
          if (i + 1 == strings.length){
            checker.finalCheck = true;
          }
          await new Promise(resolve => checker.check(resolve, strings[i]));
          if (checker.finalCheck){
            updateTimeStamp(Date.now());
          }
        }
      }
      runLoop();
```

For those who wonder onto this looking for an answer, the await pauses your execution until the resolve is met. You pass resolve onto your function, and inside the setInterval() code block, at the very end you call resolve(). In order to use the await, the whole thing gets wrapped up inside of an async.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems like as though you want to have some kind of schedule of appointments that you'd like "messages" to be received at and if a message is not ready at the appointment, then you'd like it to reschedule to the next appointment. You can easily find the next available appointment with some kind of iteration

```js
const nextCheckin = (lastCheckin, interval) => {
  while (lastCheckin < Date.now())
    last += delay
  return last
}
```

Assuming the order of messages matters you can do something like such

```
const simulation = (strings, delay) => {
  let checkin = Date.now() + delay
  for (const str of strings) {
    const result = simulate(str)
    checkin = nextCheckin(checkin, delay)
    console.log(`Waiting for: ${checkin-Date.now()}`)
    while (Date.now() < checkin)
      continue
    reportWork(result)
  }
}
```

The while loop will cause the event loop to hang, so maybe a call to `setTimeout` would be more appropriate, but whatever floats a boat.